# FALSE VALUE TO NOTHING IN EXCEL CELL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three set of data. Branch A and B is the expected addition of Branch A + Branch B
[image]
For Validation reasons Branch A and B Total, Branch A and Branch B are sent from different sources and location to me. My duty is to evaluate if the data add up eg. In Jan-15 I will check if the values in cell B10 added to B6 equals B2 “(B10+B6)=B2)” if they are the same I want to display TRUE. If they are False I want to display nothing in the Cell.
I tried this formula see Image attached

```
=IF(((B10+B6)=B2)="FALSE","",(B10+B6)=B2)
```

It is not working. I have been told not to format FALSE white (Which would have been easier for me).

Expected OUTPUT
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about -

```
=IF(((B10+B6)=B2),(B10+B6)=B2,"")
```

This will print the correct amount if they are equal else will print nothing at all.

Comment: You can simplify this to 
=IF((B10+B6)=B2,TRUE,"")

Comment: @AlexM, Completely agreed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another solution:

```
=TEXT(B10+B6-B2,";;""True""")
```

This method makes use of custom number formatting:

- The first two sections of the number format are left blank, so if there's a difference, it won't get displayed at all
- The third section (the one after second semi-colon `;`) contains the literal "True" which gets displayed when the result is 0.
- The double double quotes around the `True` translates to quotation marks, which makes the text wrapped inside them to be displayed as it is.